# Is it incorrect to say "he/she is the perfect body type"?

Tags: sentence-construction

The common form would be: "he/she has the perfect body type."

Would it be strange to say: "he/she is the perfect body type"?

Google only return [2](https://www.google.com.tw/search?rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&ei=EL6cWrjfMsai0gSs8pOwDw&q=%22she%20is%20the%20perfect%20body%22&oq=%22she%20is%20the%20perfect%20body%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...62822.62900.0.62996.2.2.0.0.0.0.54.101.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.46...0i8i30k1.0.Favb7iIXYbg) results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes a lot of sense. Can a person LITERALLY be a body type? I think they can definitely possess a body type, just not be it. Probably why it pulled so few results.